# jQuery snapPuzzle put multiple clicks on last piece

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, puzzle

Ok, so I'm creating a project for my Masters for inducing frustration in a lab setting and I am using this plugin for a jigsaw puzzle: https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/snap-puzzle/demo.html

What I would like to do is make the puzzle "break" on the very last piece to cause frustration, so they would have to click on the piece 5 times before they can drag it to it's slot. I'm not fantastic with Javascript and the functions are a little complex so I am at a bit of a loss as to how to do this and there seems to be more help out there for getting rid of multiple clicks rather than causing them.

As far as I have got is - in the jquery.snap-puzzle.js file at the end it defines the actions for when the last slot is filled and I have tried a few times to tweak it but I keep breaking it... Anybody have any ideas about how to require 5 clicks before the last piece can be moved?

If it makes much of a difference, I'm using Angular for my front end...

**Edit: as advised by @Martieva I added a click incrementer like so:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.snapPuzzle = function(options){
        var o = $.extend({ pile: '', containment: 'document', rows: 5,   columns: 5, onComplete: function(){} }, options);

    // public methods
    if (typeof options == 'string') {
        this.each(function(){
            var that = $(this),
                o = that.data('options'),
                pieceWidth = that.width() / o.columns,
                pieceHeight = that.height() / o.rows,
                pile = $(o.pile),
                maxX = pile.width() - pieceWidth,
                maxY = pile.height() - pieceHeight,
                puzzle_offset = that.closest('span').offset(),
                pile_offset = pile.offset();

            if (options == 'destroy') {
                $('.'+o.puzzle_class).remove();
                that.unwrap().removeData('options');
                pile.removeClass('snappuzzle-pile');
            } else if (options == 'refresh') {
                $('.snappuzzle-slot.'+o.puzzle_class).each(function(){
                    var x_y = $(this).data('pos').split('_'), x = x_y[0], y = x_y[1];
                    $(this).css({
                        width: pieceWidth,
                        height: pieceHeight,
                        left: y*pieceWidth,
                        top: x*pieceHeight
                    });
                });
                $('.snappuzzle-piece.'+o.puzzle_class).each(function(){
                    if ($(this).data('slot')) {
                        // placed on slot
                        var x_y = $(this).data('slot').split('_'), slot_x = x_y[0], slot_y = x_y[1],
                            x_y = $(this).data('pos').split('_'), pos_x = x_y[0], pos_y = x_y[1];;
                        $(this).css({
                            width: pieceWidth,
                            height: pieceHeight,
                            left: slot_y*pieceWidth+puzzle_offset.left-pile_offset.left,
                            top: slot_x*pieceHeight+puzzle_offset.top-pile_offset.top,
                            backgroundPosition: (-pos_y*pieceWidth)+'px '+(-pos_x*pieceHeight)+'px',
                            backgroundSize: that.width()
                        });
                    } else {
                        // placed anywhere else
                        var x_y = $(this).data('pos').split('_'), x = x_y[0], y = x_y[1];
                        $(this).css({
                            width: pieceWidth,
                            height: pieceHeight,
                            left: Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxX+1))),
                            top: Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxY+1))),
                            backgroundPosition: (-y*pieceWidth)+'px '+(-x*pieceHeight)+'px',
                            backgroundSize: that.width()
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    function init(that){
        var puzzle_class = 'sp_'+new Date().getTime(),
            puzzle = that.wrap('<span class="snappuzzle-wrap"/>').closest('span'),
            src = that.attr('src'),
            pieceWidth = that.width() / o.columns,
            pieceHeight = that.height() / o.rows,
            pile = $(o.pile).addClass('snappuzzle-pile'),
            maxX = pile.width() - pieceWidth,
            maxY = pile.height() - pieceHeight;

        o.puzzle_class = puzzle_class;
        that.data('options', o);

        for (var x=0; x<o.rows; x++) {
            for (var y=0; y<o.columns; y++) {
                $('<div class="snappuzzle-piece '+puzzle_class+'"/>').data('pos', x+'_'+y).css({
                    width: pieceWidth,
                    height: pieceHeight,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxX+1))),
                    top: Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxY+1))),
                    zIndex: Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1),
                    backgroundImage: 'url('+src+')',
                    backgroundPosition: (-y*pieceWidth)+'px '+(-x*pieceHeight)+'px',
                    backgroundSize: that.width()
                }).draggable({
                    start: function(e, ui){ $(this).removeData('slot'); },
                    stack: '.snappuzzle-piece',
                    containment: o.containment
                }).appendTo(pile).data('lastSlot', pile);

                $('<div class="snappuzzle-slot '+puzzle_class+'"/>').data('pos', x+'_'+y).css({
                    width: pieceWidth,
                    height: pieceHeight,
                    left: y*pieceWidth,
                    top: x*pieceHeight
                }).appendTo(puzzle).droppable({
                    accept: '.'+puzzle_class,
                    hoverClass: 'snappuzzle-slot-hover',
                    drop: function(e, ui){
                        var slot_pos = $(this).data('pos');

                        // prevent dropping multiple pieces on one slot
                        $('.snappuzzle-piece.'+puzzle_class).each(function(){
                            if ($(this).data('slot') == slot_pos) slot_pos = false;
                        });
                        if (!slot_pos) return false;

                        ui.draggable.data('lastSlot', $(this)).data('slot', slot_pos);
                        ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' });

//Here is the click increment code from @Martieva
                        var clicks = 0;
                        if(ui.draggable.data('pos')==slot_pos){
                            clicks++;
                            if(clicks<5){
                                return;
                            }
                        }
//back to original code
                        if (ui.draggable.data('pos')==slot_pos) {
                            ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
                            // fix piece
                            // $(this).droppable('disable').fadeIn().fadeOut();
                            $(this).droppable('disable').css('opacity', 1).fadeOut(1000);
                            ui.draggable.css({opacity: 0, cursor: 'default'}).draggable('disable');
                            if ($('.snappuzzle-piece.correct.'+puzzle_class).length == o.rows*o.columns) o.onComplete(that);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return this.each(function(){
        if (this.complete) init($(this));
        else $(this).load(function(){ init($(this)); });
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

And here is the other script for the puzzle that needs to be included:

```
 // jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3 - must load after jQuery UI
// enables touch support for jQuery UI
!function(a){
function f(a,b){
    if(!(a.originalEvent.touches.length>1)){a.preventDefault();
        var c=a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
            d=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        d.initMouseEvent(b,!0,!0,window,1,c.screenX,c.screenY,c.clientX,c.clientY,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),
            a.target.dispatchEvent(d)
    }
}
if(a.support.touch="ontouchend"in document,a.support.touch){
    var e,b=a.ui.mouse.prototype,c=b._mouseInit,d=b._mouseDestroy;
    b._touchStart=function(a){
        var b=this;
        !e&&b._mouseCapture(a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])&&(e=!0,b._touchMoved=!1,
            f(a,"mouseover"),
            f(a,"mousemove"),
            f(a,"mousedown"))
    },
        b._touchMove=function(a){
            e&&(this._touchMoved=!0,
                f(a,"mousemove"))
        },
        b._touchEnd=function(a){
            e&&(f(a,"mouseup"),
                f(a,"mouseout"),
        this._touchMoved||f(a,"click"),
            e=!1)
    },
        b._mouseInit=function(){
        var b=this;
            b.element.bind({
                touchstart:a.proxy(b,"_touchStart"),
                touchmove:a.proxy(b,"_touchMove"),
                touchend:a.proxy(b,"_touchEnd")}),
                c.call(b)},
        b._mouseDestroy=function(){
        var b=this;b.element.unbind({
            touchstart:a.proxy(b,"_touchStart"),
            touchmove:a.proxy(b,"_touchMove"),
            touchend:a.proxy(b,"_touchEnd")}),
            d.call(b)
    }
}
}(jQuery);

function start_puzzle(x){
$('#puzzle_solved').hide();
$('#source_image').snapPuzzle({
    rows: x, columns: x,
    pile: '#pile',
    containment: '#puzzle-containment',
    onComplete: function(){
        $('#source_image').fadeOut(150).fadeIn();
        $('#puzzle_solved').show();
    }
});
}

$(function(){
$('#pile').height($('#source_image').height());
start_puzzle(5);

$('.restart-puzzle').click(function(){
    $('#source_image').snapPuzzle('destroy');
    start_puzzle($(this).data('grid'));
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#pile').height($('#source_image').height());
    $('#source_image').snapPuzzle('refresh');
});
});
```

It does not break the puzzle by any large degree, but it does not increment clicks on the final piece.

Answer (score 0):

One basic approach could be something like

```
var clicks = 0;//Needs to be of a scope that the count isn't reset between clicks.
//...The rest of your code...
if(isLastTile){//If we are dealing with the final tile.
   clicks++;
  if(clicks < 5){
   return; //Do nothing
  }
}
normalProcess();
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back so quickly, I have edited the question to include the code for the puzzle along with your suggestion. It is definitely what I was looking for but I'm afraid its probably my own understanding getting in the way, it doesn't seem to stop the drag function, but the puzzle still works ok. Any idea where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I imagine this is no longer relevant. Anyway, since you put the code within the 'drop' function you would need the declaration of the 'clicks' var to be outside of that function, probably at the top where you declare the rest of your vars in init(). That way it will be incremented without being reset. Hope you were able to get it to work!